# log4net.config is not getting published

Tags: visual-studio, logging, log4net

I m new to this logging and deployment things. I have a log4net.config file for a wcf service and it works well with my dev box. However I try to publish my code and the resulting package.zip I install in my UAT server. But when doing so I observed that the log4net.config is not getting published in the zip folder. Its not present and my logging is also not working. any thoughts anybody please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the Build Action to Content in the file properties.

[why_dont_all_files_get_deployed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx#why_dont_all_files_get_deployed)